# Change tablename on runtime by url param with Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, internationalization

I want to change some table names according to the i18N param of my URL like that : https://localhost/fr, https://localhost/en, ...
The tablename will look like : tablename_fr, tablename_en
I want to do that for simplify as most as possible the i18n transition of my website. How can i do that with Laravel ? And do you see a performance issue with this system ? Maybe it will disturb the Laravel/Eloquent cache ?

Comment: are you trying to achive translation

Comment: @Manojkiran.A I already use translation files. I have also specified content by languages in my tables. It's why I'm asking about that.

Answer (score 0):

## You could lang files for the tables.

```php
# resources/lang/en/tables
// English names for tables
return [
    'cars' => 'cars'
    'computers' => 'computers'
]
```

```php
# resources/lang/fr/tables.php
// French names for tables
return [
    'cars' => 'voitures'
    'computers' => 'ordinateurs'
]
```

Then in your views you could form urls with this using the `url()` helper. Imagine we have a `$car` with `id: 1`

```php
url(__('tables.cars').'/'.$car->id)
// if App::getLocale() === 'en', it returns /cars/1
// if App::getLocale() === 'fr', it returns /voitures/1
// if App::getLocale() === 'es', it returns /cars/1 because there's no 'es' lang file in this example and by default, 'en' is the fallback language.
```

You do need to either set up additional routing rules though.

## Alternatively, you could set up additional i18n routes and then call the route() helper

```php
# routes/web.php
// You could group the routes to add a prefix, but the idea is the same
Route::get('cars/{car}', CarController@show)->name('en.car.show');
Route::get('voitures/{car}', CarController@show)->name('fr.car.show');
```

```php
# in a view
route(App::getLocale().'.car.show', [$car->id]) 
// returns either cars/1 or voitures/1 depending on the locale
```